# Transesterification of propylene carbonate and methanol

Tags: organic-chemistry, catalysis

I'm going to try out the transesterification of propylene carbonate and methanol. I know that the mechanism is as follows :

[image: enter Transesterification]

-What are the products yielded after the reaction?

-And which catalyst should I use? (reaction is happening at normal air pressure and at room temperature)

Comment: What you have listed is not a mechanism. Also, those structures are not propylene carbonate nor methanol.  Maybe you should look at the actual structures and try to figure out yourself.

Comment: * the mechanism is an example mechanism (See the wikipedia page about transeserification)

Answer (score 3):

I know it is used to obtain  dimethyl carbonate (DMC) I think the others products should vary from which catalyst you choose. Have a look to *Transesterification of propylene carbonate with methanol using $\ce{MgAlCO3}$
hydrotalcite as solid base catalyst*: *[Indian Journal of Chemistry
Vol. 49A, September 2010, pp. 1182-1188](http://nopr.niscair.res.in/bitstream/123456789/10172/1/IJCA%2049A%289%29%201182-1188.pdf)* to choose the catalyst. I think there are two little typos in Scheme 2 where the mechanism is shown: miss $\ce{^-}$ from $\ce{CH_3O^-}$ (first step) and miss $\ce{C}$ from one part ($\ce{CH_3CO}$) of DMC formula (second step) but is a good article.